# Java get field values from DefaultTableModel and format into array

Tags: arrays, string, jtable, format, field

I am having trouble getting two of my fields from DefaultTableModel and format them into String[].

Here is how I get data from desired fields.

```
model = new DataTable().Table();
    int rowcount = model.getRowCount();

    int[] columns = {0,1}; 
    String[][] name = new String[columns.length][rowcount];
    for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
    {
        for (row = 0; row < rowcount; row++)
        {
            int column = columns[i]; 
            name[i][row] = model.getValueAt(row, column).toString();                 
        }               
    }
```

name[0] is firstname, name[1] is lastname. Now, would you please guide me how to combine these two fields as **firstname, lastname** and put it into String[] addressee?

Any inputs will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your problem. Do you need just to combine two fields?
You could create addressee directly from table.

```
String[] addressee = new String [rowcount];

          for (row = 0; row < rowcount; row++){

             addressee [row]= model.getValueAt(row, 0).toString()+" "+model.getValueAt(row, 1).toString()

    }
```